# Weird Ubuntu 18.04 iwlwifi issue

Tags: 18.04, iwlwifi

I'm having trouble connecting my laptop to a wifi network at work. I never had a problem on my home wifi, but at first it wouldn't connect at all at work. After googling around, I deleted the iwlwifi.conf file and that fixed the issue at first, but now every time I wake it up from sleep, and sometimes when I boot it up, it won't connect. It tries to connect to the network, but after failing it won't see any Wifi network. If I use the commands

```
sudo modprobe -r iwldvm
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

It'll restart the wifi and will usually connect after 1-3 tries of re-entering the commands. Any ideas how to fix it so it will stop breaking? It's an older laptop, the wireless card is a centrino advanced-n 6235.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I added "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" to a new file /etc/modprobe.d/iwlsettings.conf
(or you can add it to the end of /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf if you wish.)

This turns on TX aggregation (which basically sends several packets in one transmission instead of sending the packets one at a time..) This is off by default on some cards due to instabilities with iwlwifi and TX aggregation several years back (which are fixed now.)  Despite name "11n_disable", setting 1, 2, and 4 disable various 802.11n features, but 8 enables one.  If found a nice speedup on my 6200 turning this on, but some say (until they turn this on) performance is so low they even have problems connecting as you are seeing (it shouldn't be that slow, but I assume it's hitting some firmware bug?)

Second thing, if you can pop open your machine to get to wifi card, check the connections.  I had freezes on my 6200 the first few days I had it with no solution, and finally popped the case open only to find the card was not quite fully seated!  The little wifi antenna connectors being loose could cause problems too.